# How to have the head of a bone move freely?

Tags: armature

[image]

I've set most of the important control and pole bones and they worked, but the head of the chest bone is locked. The tail can move freely.
The file: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you select these bones in Edit mode and W > Switch Direction you don't get what you want?

Comment: When I press W in the circumstances you mentioned, it switches the type of selection tool (the cursor with the orange box and the orange circle). Switch direction also won't do it - the head is still static. There's a new picture in my post.

Answer (score 1):

This rig works normally. The bones of the spine are point to the wrong way. Unfortunatelly you have to remake those 3 bones, because now the pelvis is the children of the chest.

Comment: I've tested it and the rig doesn't work normally. The bones of the spine are supposed to bend backwards, because when he bends over, his back will make a hump. When he bends over, his head will move on the y-axis for example. As for now, the head of the marked upper back bone is locked in y- / x-/ and z-axis. I'll post another picture.

Comment: I forgot to say yesterday that the hip is supposed to be attached to the torso. That is the source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9f-WVs3ghI&t=287s

Comment: As you can see on this video the guy placed the hip bone first, then extruded the torso from it then the chest. You placed the chest first, then extruded the torso and the hip. You try to move the bone's bottom instead of the head, because your spine bones are pointing to the wrong direction.

Comment: I placed the right leg first, then the left leg, then the arms and then the torso and then i connected the legs to the torso.
I can try having the tail point upwards and then have the bones controlled by the tail. I'm a bit clueless after the things I've tried. I'll try that, I stil don't know how to mave the origin with the armature.