# Moving bone moves wrong part of body

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, pose-mode

[image]

This is weird, ive done this stick several times today and it worked well last time i did it, i think so

But now it moves body when i drag the upper body bone (just below head and invisible neck).

Desired behavior would move the head + hands + neck when i dragged this bone.

Any tips bros?

Nvm i found issue. The initial vertex has to be in the center of character (in my case the cirled yellow thing in the center of screen but below character)

Comment: answer your question on your own to close it, if you found the answer

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131383/how-to-have-the-head-of-a-bone-move-freely/131386#131386